# При нажатии на кнопку пишет "ошибка взаимодействия" ( discord py )

Tags: discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send(
        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Вы точно хотите перевести деньги?'),
        components = [
            Button(style = ButtonStyle.green, label = 'Да'),
            Button(style = ButtonStyle.red, label = 'Нет')
        ])
    responce = await bot.wait_for('button_click')
    if responce.component.label == 'Да':
        await responce.respond(content = 'Деньги успешно переведены!')
    else:
        await responce.respond(content = 'Вы отменили перевод.')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы импортировали нужную библиотеку?

```py
import discord_components
from discord_components import Button, ButtonStyle, DiscordComponents
```

2. Вы написали строчку ниже в функцию `on_ready()`? Если она у вас вообще есть. Хотя, как ее в боте не может быть.

```py
DiscordComponents(self.bot) # Для когов
DiscordComponents(bot) # Без когов
```

3. Вы ставили условие на проверку канала?

```py
responce = await bot.wait_for('button_click')
if responce.channel == ctx.channel:        
    if responce.component.label == 'Да':
        await responce.respond(content = 'Деньги успешно переведены!')
    elif responce.component.label == 'Нет':
        await responce.respond(content = 'Вы отменили перевод.')
```

Я исправил в 5-й строке моего мини-кода `else` на `elif`
.