# button discord python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Доброго времени суток.

Наткнулся на кнопки в дискорде и решил изучить, но дается трудно, не один пример из интернета не работает(

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle
import os, sys, re

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or(f"{cfg['Prefix']}"),
    case_insensitive=True,
    intents=discord.Intents.all())


adm = [937680246159835156, 915928364563451945]

class butt(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


    @commands.command()
    async def button(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Hello, World!",
            components = [Button(label = "WOW button!", custom_id = "button1")]
        )

        interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "button1")
        await interaction.send(content = "Button clicked!")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(butt(bot))
```

Команда работает, но кнопки не нажимаются, пишет "Ошибка взаимодействия"

Comment: Советую уменьшить пример до минимально воспроизводимого кода. Любителей читать длинные чужие коды, скачанные неизвестно откуда, мало. Заодно и разберётесь в нём.

Comment: по вашему совету укоротил код насколько это возможно

Comment: @Сергей теперь можно разбирать код :p

Comment: теперь ждём знатоков discord:-)

Comment: И посмотрите другие вопросы на эту тему. Например, <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1339125/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-discord-py> Например, строчку с DiscordComponents - там её считают обязательной, а в вашем коде её нет (я не знаток discord, так что просто бегло посмотрел). И поставил плюс за старательность:-) - надеюсь, привлечет желающих помочь.

Comment: @NiRBepta у меня есть ответ, но я не могу проверить точно ли это будет работать, потому что у меня возникли некоторые проблемы с библиотекой. Я разберусь и отвечу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы не намешивать библиотеки, я все же предлагаю использовать `py-cord`:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import Button, View

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Тогда обработку нажатия кнопки можно будет реализовать вот так:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello World!', view=View(
        Button(custom_id='button1', label='WOW button!', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
        ))

    interaction = await bot.wait_for('interaction', check=lambda i: i.custom_id == 'button1')
    await interaction.response.edit_message(content='Button clicked!', view=None)
```

---

Или так, через установку отдельной функции в качестве свойства отклика кнопки:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):

    async def button_callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content='Button clicked!', view=None)

    button = Button(custom_id='button1', label='WOW button!', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    button.callback = button_callback

    await ctx.send('Hello World!', view=View(button))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Всю информацию я брал из [**документации**](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=interaction#discord.Interaction). Если вам нужен был пример, то тоже не пойму как вы его не нашли, потому что я нашел идеальное видео сразу по запросу `discord buttons`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNUuYEWGOxA

Comment: Спасибо, Ваше решение очень понятно расписано, за ссылку на видео отдельное спасибо, очень помогли!